# A question about quantization and dequantization calculations

Tags: image-processing, quantization

Suppose we have a 2x2 image as follows:

[image]

What does each dequantised image look like after it has first been quantised to 7, 4 and 2 bits respectively?

I solve this question by initially quantising as follows.

1. Into 7 bits : 8 bits - 7 bits = 1 bit and 2 to the power of 1 is 2 so, 232 / 2 = 116, 127 / 2 = 63, 169 / 2 = 84 and 27 / 2 = 13. Therefore, we have:

[image]

2. Into 4 bits: 8 bits - 4 bits = 4 bits and 2 to the power of 4 equals 16. Thus, 232/16 = 14, 127 / 16 = 7, 169 / 16 = 10, 27 / 16 = 1.

[image]

3. Into 2 bits: 8 bits - 2 bits = 6 bits and 2 to the power of 6 is 128 so, 232 / 128 = 1, 127 / 128 = 0, 169 / 128 = 1 and 27 / 128 = 0 hence, we have:

[image]

Now, to dequantise the results we simply multiply each cell value by the number we initially used for quantisation. The above matrices will be as follows respectively:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Are all steps in my solution correct, if not where should be modified?

**EDIT**

According to what @Hilmar detected, 2 to the power of 6 is 64 and the quantisation into 2 bits should be changed to: 232 / 64 = 3, 127 / 64 = 1, 169 / 64 = 2 and 27 / 64 = 0 hence, we have:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to "quantize/dequantize" integer data. This should be specified to avoid different results. You have used the version:

$$ I_Q = \Delta\left\lfloor I/\Delta \right\rfloor $$

with $\Delta = 2^{8-b}$ ($b$ is the intermediate bit number) and your results seem fine with that choice. One other possible choice (better preserving bright tones) is:
$$ I_Q = \Delta\left\lceil (I+1)/\Delta \right\rceil -1 $$

Some others preserve the range, etc.

Don't hesitate to clearly state your quantization scheme, as it will be more precise than the inexact computation of rounding  `127 / 128 = 0`.

Here is a small Matlab code to recover the results:

```
B = 8; % Original bit-depth
bList = [7,4,2]; % quantized bit-depth
I = [232,127;169,27];
for b = bList
   Iq = 2^(8-b)*floor(I/2^(8-b)); % Quantized/Dequantized image
   disp(Iq)
end
```

giving the arrays:

$$
\begin{array}{rr}
   232  & 126\\
   168  &  26
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rr}
   224 &  112\\
   160 &   16
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rr}
   192  &  64\\
   128  &   0
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Apart from the quantization scheme, is the de-quantisatiopn process correct?

Comment: I have added some details, ok for 8-bit depth and the basic quantization

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> Are all steps in my solution correct,

No. Your 2 bit quantizer is clearly wrong. $2^6 = 64$ and not 128.

> if not where should be modified?

As Laurent Duval has pointed out, that depends a lot on the specific choice of your quantizer. What are your quantization steps, do you round or truncate, how do manage "out of bound" conditions, etc.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I edit the question. How about the de-quantisation, is it correct?

Comment: We cannot answer this until you define your quantization and de-quantization process. There is more than one "correct" answer.